# A finding a probability mass function with a floor function in it

Tags: probability, random-variables, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$. For any given real number $a$ let $\lfloor a \rfloor$ denote the largest integer no greater than $a$. If $q$ is a given constant such that $q \in (0,1)$

> **Find the pmf of $X = 1+\left\lfloor\frac{\ln U}{\ln q}\right\rfloor$.**

I get an idea of what is going on by look at the question [Find the probability mass function of the (discrete) random variable $X = Int(nU) + 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307877/find-the-probability-mass-function-of-the-discrete-random-variable-x-intnu) My problem is I can't quite figure out how to handle the $\log$ functions and the fact that $\ln q$ in not always an integer.

Comment: Can you find $P(1 \leq 1+ \frac{\log U}{\log q} \leq 2)$?

Comment: @madprob Looks like your probability should be $1-q$, correct? I'm not sure how this helps.

Comment: $P(X=n) = P(n \leq 1+ \frac{\log U}{\log q} < n +1)$. You should solved $P(X=1)$ :)

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=n) = P(n-1< \frac{\log U}{\log{q}} < n ) = P(n\log(q)  < \log U < \log(q) (n-1)) = P(q^{n} < U < q^{n-1}) = q^{n-1} - q^n = q^{n-1}(1-q)$